# Up-to-date password manager with import CSV option

Tags: software-recommendation, password, security, passphrase

I just tried KeePassX with high hopes ( I see it referenced everywhere) only to find that it doesn't have an option for importing a CSV file.

I have ***many*** passwords that are **very** long (50+ chars.) and they're with LastPass, a browser extension that isn't fully updated for Firefox 55 yet. As such, I can't search my passwords unless I open the vault which takes forever. I have to do this every time I need to log in to a local application that connects to the internet. This is very annoying and I would like a local one that I can have an indicator for a search for what I need without leaving the current application.

I have exported all of my passwords into a CSV file and am looking for a manager that has an option for importing from a CSV file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think **Universal Password Manager** will help you in this condition. It has an ability to import from CSV.

**Features:**

- Simplicity - it provides a small number of very strong features with
  no clutter
- Cross platform - UPM runs on Android, Windows, Mac OS X and Linux
- Database syncing - This feature allows your to keep you database in
  sync across several PCs/devices using either Dropbox or a HTTP
  location.

**Key Features:**

- Small, fast and lean
- Uses AES for database encryption
- Database sync across multiple PCs/devices
- Written in Java/SWING
- Android, Windows and Mac OS X native feeling versions available
- Fast account searching
- Streamlined for those who are more comfortable using the keyboard
  only

How to install:

Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter each of these lines seperately on the terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:adriansmith/upm
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install upm
```

You can find it under **Accessories Menu**.

If you are using Ubuntu version that is unavailable to run **upm** from repository, then download **upm** from http://upm.sourceforge.net/download.html under **Linux** tag, then store it where it should be.

Then, Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter each of these lines seperately on the terminal:

```
cd /path/to/zip
sudo apt update
sudo apt install openjdk-9-headless
tar xzf upm-x.xx.tar.gz
cd upm-x.xx
sh upm.sh
```

If you want to make a shortcut on your desktop, do the following:

- Right click on your desktop
- Choose "Create Launcher..."
- Change "Application" to "Application in Terminal" in the drop down box.
- Give it a name like "UPM"
- Enter the command like this `/path/to/upm-x.xx/upm.sh`
- Add a comment if you like, it will show up when you mouse hover over it if you move the launcher to a menu bar.

Comment: Do you know, off the top of your head, if it's available somewhere for Zesty? I'm running Ubuntu 17.04. I didn't think to add it to the question. Also, how did you get CTRL+ALT+T to appear as buttons?

Comment: Just download from here - http://upm.sourceforge.net/download.html . If the If upm-1.14.tar.gz does not work, compile it.

Comment: Using kbd tag makes text to be appeared as buttons

Comment: I updated my answer, check whether it works...